# Relative path with zip in vrt file (vsizip)?

Tags: docker, gis, tiff, zip, gdal

I am trying to build a vrt file with a lot of zipped tiff files.
I found that this xml-command adds a tiff file inside a zip file to the vrt:

```
<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">/vsizip/c:/data/DSM_633_54_TIF_UTM32-ETRS89.zip/DSM_1km_6333_546.tif</SourceFilename>
```

This works fine, but the problem is that it only works with the **absolute path**. Since I am working in docker, I cannot use the absolute path, only the relative.

If I just use the relative path it can't seem to find the images (it is all black and has values at 1e[huge number] when I open it in QGis).

**Is there any way to use the *relative path* when adding a tiff image inside a zip file to a vrt??**

Comment: Just found this: http://erouault.blogspot.dk/2011/12/seamless-access-to-remote-global-multi.html looks interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use absolute paths:

Here is an example (noticet he double forward slash).

```
pksorensen@swarm-master-4D58E13F-0:~$ docker -H 172.16.0.5:2375 run --rm -v $(docker -H 172.16.0.5:2375 volume create -d azurefile -o share=dhm-danmarks-hoejdemodel):/data  geodata/gdal gdalinfo /vsizip//data/DSM_633_54_TIF_UTM32-ETRS89.zip/DSM_1km_6333_546.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vsizip//data/DSM_633_54_TIF_UTM32-ETRS89.zip/DSM_1km_6333_546.tif
Size is 2500, 2500
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","25832"]]
Origin = (546000.000000000000000,6334000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.400000000000000,-0.400000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  546000.000, 6334000.000) (  9d45'36.85"E, 57d 8'49.01"N)
Lower Left  (  546000.000, 6333000.000) (  9d45'36.19"E, 57d 8'16.67"N)
Upper Right (  547000.000, 6334000.000) (  9d46'36.34"E, 57d 8'48.65"N)
Lower Right (  547000.000, 6333000.000) (  9d46'35.66"E, 57d 8'16.31"N)
Center      (  546500.000, 6333500.000) (  9d46' 6.26"E, 57d 8'32.66"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Ofcause this means that we assume that the generated vrt file will have the same volume bindings for any call after - but I think that should be fine :)